# Proof that this is a complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, complete-spaces

How do I prove that a metric space defined by ($A,d$), where $A$ is any set and $d$ is the distance defined by

$\displaystyle d(x,y) = \left\{ 1, \ \text{if} \ x \neq y \atop
0, \ \text{if} \ x = y \right.$

is complete? I know I have to prove that any Cauchy sequence is convergent to a limit, and that the limit must be inside the set, but I don't know how to begin the proof.

Comment: Let $(x_n)$ a Cauchy sequence, i.e. there is $N$ s.t. $d(x_n,x_m)<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n,m\geq N$, i.e. $d(x_n,x_m)=0$ for all $n,m\geq N$, i.e. $x_n=x_N$ for all $n\geq N$, i.e. $(x_n)$ converges to $x_{N}$.

Comment: Perhaps it's easier to work with a concrete metric space.